# craft_cache / Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry, Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock

Tags: cache, error-message, logs

Noticing these errors a lot it my logs. Any idea why, or how to stop it from happening?

`Jan 27 15:02:58 myapp.com ool: myapp: [craft] [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'b790ee3c633c1693d2140bfae35b65fe' for key 'PRIMARY'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO craft_cache (id,expire,value) VALUES ('b790ee3c633c1693d2140bfae35b65fe',1485633775,:value).`

Update - also seeing:

`Jan 27 15:49:58 myapp.com ool: myapp: [craft] [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction. The SQL statement executed was: DELETE FROM craft_cache WHERE expire>0 AND expire<1485550196.`

Notes:

- I'm not using any template level caching (site is Varnished)
- My `cacheMethod` is 'db'
- Load balanced setup (1 LB, 2 web heads, 1 LB, 1 DB)
- Looking up the key in the latter example, it is a serialized object of `Craft\SearchPlus_AlgoliaMapModel` (plugin). However, looking at the SearchPlus code I'm pretty it the plugin itself isn't storing this. It has one call to `craft()->cache->set` and it just stores a string.

Comment: The error is pretty clear... can you catch a full stack trace with devMode enabled so you can see which template it's originating from?

Comment: That's a bit tricky as I'm only currently seeing it in production. I added several more details in the original post. I'm more just curious how this is even possible through a simple `craft()->cache->set` / `CDbCache\setValue` call.